# Return an object in a role in Python and get a reference of another object in QML

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

I'm writing a Twitter client. I implemented `TweetItem` and `TweetModel`. The issue is that there is a role in `TweetItem` called `original`. I want it to point to the original tweet.

Update: There were some typo in my code. Now I fixed them.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtDeclarative


class TweetModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, prototype, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setRoleNames(prototype.roleNames())
        self.tweets = []

    def appendRow(self, item):
        self.tweets.append(item)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.tweets)

    def data(self, index, role):
        return self.tweets[index.row()].data(role)


class TweetItem(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, id=None, original=None, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.idRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1
        # More Roles
        self.originalRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 6

        self.id = id
        self.original = original

    def roleNames(self):
        names = {}
        names[self.idRole] = "id"
        names[self.originalRole] = "original"
        return names

    def data(self, role):
        if role == self.idRole:
            return self.id
        elif role == self.originalRole:
            # self.original == <__main__.TweetItem object at 0x7fb703d95d40>
            return self.original
        else:
            return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = TweetModel(TweetItem())
    item = TweetItem("0001", None, model)
    model.appendRow(TweetItem("0002", item, model))

    App = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView()
    view.rootContext().setContextProperty("mymodel", model)
    view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("main.qml"))
    view.show()
    App.exec_()
```

But I can not use it in  QML. I get an `undefined` value.

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
  width: 360
  height: 360

  ListView {
         anchors.fill: parent
         model: mymodel
         // original.id == undefined
         delegate: Component { Text { text: id + " " + original.id } }
  } 
}
```

So, is it possible to return an object in a `role` and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested by [dant3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2272176/dant3) use QObject with properties.

Here is an example how to do it:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtDeclarative
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtProperty, pyqtSignal, QObject


class TweetModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, prototype, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setRoleNames(prototype.roles)
        self.tweets = []

    def appendRow(self, item):
        self.tweets.append(item)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.tweets)

    def data(self, index, role):
        return self.tweets[index.row()].data(role)


class TweetItem(QObject):
    roles = {
        QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1: 'id',
        QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 6: 'original',
    }

    id_changed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, id=None, original=None, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self._data = {'original': original}
        self.id = id

    def data(self, key):
        return self._data[self.roles[key]]

    @pyqtProperty(str, notify=id_changed)
    def id(self):
        return self._data['id']

    @id.setter
    def id(self, value):
        if self._data.get('id') != value:
            self._data['id'] = value
            self.id_changed.emit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = TweetModel(TweetItem)
    item = TweetItem("0001", None, model)
    model.appendRow(TweetItem("0002", item, model))

    App = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView()
    view.rootContext().setContextProperty("mymodel", model)
    view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("main.qml"))
    view.show()
    App.exec_()
```

The QML file remains the same.

I didn't make `original` a property, since you get it as model data, but you can make it in the same fashion as `id`.

Comment: That's works! Thanks a lot! I'm going to close this question :)

Comment: You solution works perfectly. But Qt will segfault in some cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112136/pyqt-segfault-when-trying-to-get-a-sub-sub-property-in-qml

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you got undefined not on accessing your **TweetItem** object, but on trying to get id out of it.

As it looks, your implementation of ***QAbstractItemModel*** in **TweetItem** is simply incorrect. Not does it's data method accepts any index, nor it implements rowCount. Consult Qt documentation on how to implement ***QAbstractItemModel*** interface correctly if you still wan't to use it.

My advice, to achieve what you want, is to subclass **QObject** instead and provide your additional data as it's named properties to use them in QML. See this [**page of Qt guidelines on how to bind your QObject with QML**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#modifying-properties).

Comment: I found I can not access any property/Slot of TweetItem. Even it is a simple subclass from `QObject`. How can I "export" them to QML dynamicly?

Comment: try [qmlRegisterType function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeengine.html#qmlRegisterType)

Comment: I tried it. My app will broken after I `qmlRegisterType(TweetItem, "tweetItem", 1, 0, "tweetItem")`. QML Engine said `Cannot assign object to list`. But I even didn't import it yet?!

Comment: [PyQt doesn't support qmlRegisterType](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg26485.html). PySide [does](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/blobs/master/examples/declarative/extending/chapter1-basics/basics.py), although I'm not sure about status of the project.

Comment: I think you didn't imported your "tweetItem" module. Try to add `import tweetItem 1.0` in your QML @比尔盖子

Comment: @比尔盖子 also see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16065787/2272176), it contains sample code witch I think will do it

Comment: @ dant3 I switched to PySide to use `qmlRegisterType`. QML `Engine said Cannot assign object to list`, no matter what I import it or not. It is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

1. Straight answer: you got `undefined` because, because your `TweetItem.original` is in fact `None`.
2. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I want to clear some possible misunderstandings. `QAbstractItemModel` is a model class too, it's somewhat strange to see

   ```
   def data(self, index, role):
       return self.tweets[index.row()].data(role)
   ```

there.

Comment: ad 2: Just curious, why do you consider this strange? If it's because of delegating `data` to the tweet, this is just what is done in one of Qt's examples, apart from the fact that the OP also passes the role: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-simpletreemodel-treemodel-cpp.html

Comment: `TweetItem.original` is not None, I can get the object in Python, but I got undefined in QML. Maybe it's a garbage collection's issue?