# PyQt segfault when trying to get a sub-sub-property in QML

Tags: python, qt, segmentation-fault, pyqt

I was trying to [Return an object in a role in Python and get a reference of another object in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306872/return-an-object-in-a-role-in-python-and-get-a-reference-of-another-object-in-qm). Finally, I found I can use `Property` to do it.

But, I want to get a reference of another reference of another object in QML, PyQt just segfault. I switched to PySide but it was still crashing when I run it.

Did I doing something wrong?

GDB said

```
Cannot access memory at address 0xb
Cannot access memory at address 0x3
```

main.py

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtDeclarative
from PySide.QtCore import Property, Signal, QObject


class TweetModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, prototype, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setRoleNames(prototype.roles)
        self.tweets = []

    def appendRow(self, item):
        self.tweets.append(item)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.tweets)

    def data(self, index, role):
        return self.tweets[index.row()].data(role)


class UserItem(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, item, parent=None):
        super(UserItem, self).__init__()
        self._data = item

    @QtCore.Property(str)
    def name(self):
        return self._data.get('name')


class TweetItem(QObject):
    roles = {
        QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1: 'id',
        QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 6: 'original',
    }

    id_changed = Signal()

    def __init__(self, id=None, original=None, author=None, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self._data = {'original': original,
                'id': id, 'author': author}

    def data(self, key):
        return self._data[self.roles[key]]

    @Property(str, constant=True)
    def id(self):
        return self._data['id']

    @Property(QtCore.QObject, constant=True)
    def original(self):
        return self._data['original']

    @Property(QtCore.QObject, constant=True)
    def author(self):
        return UserItem(self._data['author'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = TweetModel(TweetItem)
    item = TweetItem("0001", None, {'name': 'test'}, model)
    item_2 = TweetItem("0002", item, None, model)
    item_3 = TweetItem("0003", item_2, None, model)
    model.appendRow(item_3)

    App = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView()
    view.rootContext().setContextProperty("mymodel", model)
    view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("main.qml"))
    view.show()
    App.exec_()
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: mymodel
        delegate: Item { 
            Text { 
                text: id + " " + original.id + " " + original.original.author.name
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is [garbage collection](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/gotchas.html#garbage-collection) issue.

Your `UserItem` that you make in `author` method isn't referenced anywhere afterwards in python code and gets garbage collected.

To avoid this, you can make `UserItem` in your `main`:

```
item = TweetItem("0001", None, UserItem({'name': 'test'}), model)
```

or store it in `TweetItem` upon creation:

```
if not self._author:
    self._author = UserItem(self._data['author'])
return self._author
```

I'd probably do the first way or maybe pass dict to the `TweetItem` and convert it to `UserItem` in `__init__`:

```
self._data = {'original': original,
        'id': id, 'author': UserItem(author)}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest