# Can't pass a QAbstractListModel to QML

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5, qabstractlistmodel

I'm following [this PySide tutorial](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Selectable-list-of-Python-objects-in-QML) as close as possible using PyQt5. When I run my code, I get this error: `ReferenceError: pythonListModel is not defined`, and the list shows up black with no items.

This is my code

```
def main():
    platform = Platform("Windows")
    platform_wrp = qml_platforms.PlatformsWrapper(platform)
    platform_model = qml_platforms.PlatformsListModel([platform_wrp])
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine(QUrl("main.qml"))
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty('pythonListModel', platform_model)
    window = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my model and wrapper

```
class PlatformsWrapper(QObject):
    def __init__(self, platform):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.platform = platform
    def full_name(self):
        return str(self.platform.full_name)
    changed = pyqtSignal()
    full_name = pyqtProperty("QString", _full_name, notify=changed)

class PlatformsListModel(QAbstractListModel):
     def __init__(self, platforms):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.platforms = platforms
     def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
         return len(self.platforms)
     def data(self, index):
         if index.isValid():
             return self.platforms[index.row()]
         return None
```

and my QML

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow{
ListView {
    id: pythonList
    width: 400
    height: 200

    model: pythonListModel

    delegate: Component {
        Rectangle {
            width: pythonList.width
            height: 40
            color: ((index % 2 == 0)?"#222":"#111")
            Text {
                id: title
                elide: Text.ElideRight
                text: model.platform.full_name
                color: "white"
                font.bold: true
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
                anchors.fill: parent
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Why can't Qt find my contextProperty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that "main.qml" is loaded before you set context property. Try load file after you setup your context:

```
def main():
    platform = Platform("Windows")
    platform_wrp = qml_platforms.PlatformsWrapper(platform)
    platform_model = qml_platforms.PlatformsListModel([platform_wrp])
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty('pythonListModel', platform_model)
    engine.load( QUrl("main.qml") ) #load after context setup
    window = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets rid of the `ReferenceError`, but now I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'full_name' of undefined`. It seems it can't read the property for some reason

Comment: Took a whole lot of googling, but I managed to find out how to assign roles with PyQt5, found that in an unrelated SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306872/return-an-object-in-a-role-in-python-and-get-a-reference-of-another-object-in-qm