# Can't display data from QSqlQueryModel in a QML TableView

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I'm trying to display data from a MySQL database in a table with the help of `TableView`component of QML.

Initially I tried making a `QSqlQueryModel` object from a `QSqlQuery` object and pass it to QML context as a property. But I came to know from [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) that I must implement  `roleNames()` to supply column to role mapping to `TableView`, so I subclassed `QSqlQueryModel` like so

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel


class QtTabModel(QSqlQueryModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtTabModel, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def roleNames():
        roles = {
            Qt.UserRole + 1 : "id",
            Qt.UserRole + 2 : "name"
        }
        return roles

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
view = QQuickView()
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("qtdb")
db.setUserName("abc")
db.setPassword("xyz")
qry = QSqlQuery()
if db.open():
    qry = db.exec("SELECT id, name FROM qttab")
tabmodel = QtTabModel()
tabmodel.setQuery(qry)
ctx = view.rootContext()
ctx.setContextProperty("tabmodel", tabmodel)
view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("sqltabletest.qml"))
view.show()
app.exec()
```

and my QML is

```js
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

TableView {
    width: 200
    height: 300
    model: tabmodel
}
```

but it's showing nothing, just a blank window

[image: blank window from Qt5 in Ubuntu 14.04]

I can see my `QSqlQuery` is working as I can print data from database using `value(n)` method from that query. I've also checked with making `rolenames()` member function, but the end result is same.

```python
def roleNames(self):
    roles = {
        Qt.UserRole + 1 : "id",
        Qt.UserRole + 2 : "name"
    }
    return roles
```

### Update:

`QSqlQueryModel` works with widget classes, I've tested it with `QTableView` widget. But I need to make it work with QML.

```python
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("qtdb")
db.setUserName("abc")
db.setPassword("xyz")
qry = QSqlQuery()
if db.open():
    qry = db.exec("SELECT id, name FROM qttab")
tabmodel = QSqlQueryModel()
tabmodel.setQuery(qry)
tabmodel.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
tabmodel.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
tabview = QTableView()
tabview.setModel(tabmodel)
tabview.show()
db.close()
app.exec()
```

[image: working Qt5 code]

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe roleNames should not be a static method.

Comment: @fxam I've tried without the decorator too, making it member method; same result :(

Comment: Maybe you can get some idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306872/return-an-object-in-a-role-in-python-and-get-a-reference-of-another-object-in-qm), although it's for PyQt4.

Comment: I've went through that question, unfortunately the code in question is directly inheriting `QAbstractItemModel` and the problem is in implementation of `rowCount` and `data` methods and about accessing a particular member from QML. In my question I'm inheriting [`QSqlQueryModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquerymodel.html) class which already has implementation for `data` and `rowCount`. I'm also not trying to explicitly access any member of that derived class. Can you please explain if I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, your comment reminded me that you indeed need to reimplement `data()` for the sake of QML's model. Why? Because QML's model calls `data()` with the roles given by roleName(). It doesn't call `data()` with `Qt::DisplayRole` like in QWidget world. Furthermore, you need to define `TableViewColumn` with role names, otherwise model will not call `data()`. Here's an example of how you can reimplement `data()`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt, QVariant
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel

class QtTabModel(QSqlQueryModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtTabModel, self).__init__()

    def roleNames(self):
        roles = {
            Qt.UserRole + 1 : 'id',
            Qt.UserRole + 2 : 'name'
        }
        return roles

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role < Qt.UserRole:
            # caller requests non-UserRole data, just pass to papa
            return super(QtTabModel, self).data(index, role)

        # caller requests UserRole data, convert role to column (role - Qt.UserRole -1) to return correct data
        return super(QtTabModel, self).data(self.index(index.row(), role - Qt.UserRole -1), Qt.DisplayRole)

    @pyqtSlot(result=QVariant)  # don't know how to return a python array/list, so just use QVariant
    def roleNameArray(self):
        # This method is used to return a list that QML understands
        list = []
        # list = self.roleNames().items()
        for key, value in self.roleNames().items():
            list.append(value)

        return QVariant(list)
```

Add `TableViewColumn` to `TableView`. Keep in mind that role are case-sensitive. They must match exactly with what roleNames() returns:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

TableView {
    width: 200
    height: 300
    model: tabmodel
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "id" // case-sensitive, must match a role returned by roleNames()
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "name"
    }

}
```

Here's a way to automatically generate TableViewColumn. It calls roleNameArray slot defined in python code above to get the role name list. We don't call roleNames() here since I don't know how to make QML understand the result it returns :), so we have to convert it to a list. Finally we loop through the list and call TableView.addColumn to create columns:

```
TableView {
    width: 200
    height: 300
    model: tabmodel
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var roles = model.roleNameArray()
        for (var i=0; i<roles.length; i++) {
          var column = addColumn( Qt.createQmlObject(
            "import QtQuick.Controls 1.1; TableViewColumn {}",
            this) )
          column.role = roles[i]
          column.title = roles[i]
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works correctly. But as you've mentioned I also need to create table columns in QML manually, which kind of gives up the separation between my data model and data view, right? In case of widget classes I only need to pass the model to the view and columns will be created automatically from column-names of query results(ignoring the case I've manually passed column names :P). Is there any way to achieve that from QML ?